# Symfony 3.4 creates "prod?" cache directory

Tags: symfony, caching

I'm currently using Symfony 3.4.8 with up to date dependencies.

In production, symfony creates "prod?" directory :

```
drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data  434 Apr 20 10:26 . 
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data   45 Apr 20 10:21 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data  165 Apr 20 10:26 annotations.map
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data  15K Apr 20 10:26 ContainerDcnvgsr
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 106K Apr 20 10:26 srcProd?DebugProjectContainerCompiler.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data  628 Apr 20 10:26 srcProd?DebugProjectContainerDeprecations.log
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data  784 Apr 20 10:26 srcProd?DebugProjectContainer.php
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data  21K Apr 20 10:26 srcProd?DebugProjectContainer.php.meta
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 347K Apr 20 10:21 srcProd?DebugProjectContainer.xml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data  21K Apr 20 10:21 srcProd?DebugProjectContainer.xml.meta
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data    0 Apr 20 10:21 vich_uploader
```

var/cache directory :

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data  45 Apr 20 10:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data www-data  44 Apr 19 11:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 9 www-data www-data 556 Apr 19 11:42 prod
drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data 434 Apr 20 10:26 prod?
```

public directory :

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data  104 Apr 19 11:39 build
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data   27 Apr 19 11:38 bundles
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data   98 Apr 19 09:27 imports
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 1242 Apr 19 09:27 index.php
```

Most of users have the following error :

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
> 'DebugProjectContainer' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

The app works for few users with the correct "prod" cache directory and no error.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you paste a `ls web/` and `ls var/cache` ?

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe remove var/cache completely and rebuild the cache with bin/console cache:clear --env=prod.  Though I suspect you may have already done so.

Comment: @FlorentDestremau Post updated.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, already done.. :(

Comment: the "?" is really weird, check for you configuration files to see if there isn't a "?" hanging somewhere.

Comment: Maybe check the files permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a special character (^M) at the end of each line in the .env file due to a bad copy/paste.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯